# PHP Basic encryption/decryption for URL parameters

Tags: php, url, parameters, encryption

I'm creating a standard 'framework' in PHP for my own projects.
On this point I want to have certain URL parameters encrypted. Those variables will not contain any data I need to hide from anyone. There are some restrictions.

- No security involved at all
- Decryption
- Basic characters only (A-Z,a-z,0-9)
- Optionally salt
- Optionally limit length

I've searched the internet, but all contained characters I did not prefer due to my htaccess standards. People that asked the same question often get point at security leaving no suitable answer in my case.
Has anybody encountered this, and has a solution for this which I think must be basic?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: confused question full of contradictions.

Comment: If you don't need to hide the data from anyone, why encrypt it?

Comment: Because I like the way it looks in the URL and nobody needs to edit those anyhow.

Comment: You could search for old encryption formats even used by the Romans. Rewrite the encryption into php and you are done.

Comment: Encryption for vanity.  That's a first!

Comment: well that's the most ridiculous justification for stupidity I have seen this week.

Comment: Oh, pity those thousands fools struggling for pretty urls!!

Comment: It'd be a shame if bjice was harassed for simply mislabeling url-shortening as encryption. Give the guy a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not everybody understands what you want ( including me ).
You just want to make a "strange cool Url" ?

Replace a string with anything you want.

```
$string ="ace";

$letters    =array( "a"=>'1',"b"=>'2',"c"=>'3',"d"=>'4',"e"=>'5');#etc.

$numbers       = strtr($string, $letters);
## outputs : 135
```

EDIT :
I think I figured out what you want.

Making a tiny url like youtube does.

Take a look here : http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/

Comment: Your edit was exactly what I was looking for. Because I did not have any psysical teaching at all at web developing, I have some trouble to explain to others. (Sorry for late reply)